# inherited property conflict in coredata with inheritance model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-design

I have an app that comes with pre-populated statements (StatementModel) for questions(QuestionModel).

User can create their own statement(UserStatement) when they are in the question, or they can just copy paste the pre-populated statement and keep working on it and save it which then be saved as a user statement(UserStatement) as well.

I have below schema in coredata. I made the statement parent entity for user statement since they share a lot of properties. However I do have one problem here. From the question, I need to find a way to reference user statements and statements separately.

In our current schema, I do have statements and userStatements relationship to each of the entity and each entity has question to connect to that but I am getting conflict property error. Am I thinking this wrong?

Thanks.
 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a relationship with the same name as in its parent class.

Rename one of the `question` relationships to something else. Better even, eliminate one of them.

Comment: the reason I have to keep question in both statement is, I would like to know what question those statements belong to. I could name 'question' differently but that would create inconsistency in my schema. The more I think about this, the more I think I should not have parent here. I separated them and it works in my case.

Comment: My suggestion does not question your data model. We have not discussed this point, so I trust you made your decision correctly. Just **rename** the relationship to avoid the conflict. Your convoluted entity names do not contribute to clarity either. (e.g. eliminate the suffix "Model" and drop the "QWZ" prefix.)